# How do I reference an empty JPanel with a method like getComponent()?

Tags: java, swing

As the question states, I want to know how I can reference an empty JPanel. Here is my little code snippet:

```
try
{                           
    if(tiles[3][3].getComponent(0) == null)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "true");
    }
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
}
```

In this example I want to reference the JPanel at 3,3 (which is empty) and getComponent() will throw an exception, seeing as there is no nth component. getComponents doesn't work either because their is no component. I tried with:

```
if(tiles[3][3].getComponents == null)
```

and that still didn't work.

Specifically with this question, I want to use an empty tile in an if statement so that I can check if the tile is empty, and if it is then I will do something with it.

Comment: What type is `tiles`?

Comment: Why not just "if(tiles[3][3] == null) {" ?

Comment: @RealSkeptic tiles is an array of JPanels.

Comment: @BarrySW19 Because that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an array item has the potential to be null, you have to check whether it's null before you try accessing any methods that relate to it. So check whether `tiles[3][3] == null`.

Once you have established that it is not null, you have to call either the `getComponents()` method or the `getComponentCount()` method.

Note that these are methods, not elements, so you have to call them with the braces.

The `getComponents()` method returns an array of components, so you have to check the length of the array.

The `getComponentCount()` returns an integer indicating the number of components in the JPanel.

The method `getComponent(N)` (singular, not plural) requires that the component with the given index is inside your JPanel, so it will not work with an empty JPanel.

Comment: That didn't work 
EDIT: Specifically, I'm looking to check the components of a JPanel and need to know how to reference it if it's empty. In this example tiles[3][3] IS empty. I just need to know how to reference it within the if statement.

Comment: You can't reference a null. If it's null it means that there is no actual JPanel there.

Comment: Ok, that doesn't answer the question though. Let me rephrase it, maybe the question is vague or not worded correctly, I don't know. How do I check if a JPanel has no components inside of it without throwing an exception, in the way I try in the example? aka if(JPanel is empty)

Comment: Also, when I plug this in to the actual program, the tile doesn't equal null, meaning it's actually there.

Comment: I think the reason for the confusion is that you said `getComponents()` throws an exception. It doesn't do so for an empty JPanel. That's why I assumed you were trying to access a null reference. Why don't you edit your question and explain exactly which exception gets thrown?

Comment: I edited the question, I didn't word it correctly I guess. I made my question a lot more direct in what I'm asking too.

Comment: I guess "if(tiles[3][3] != null && tiles[3][3].getComponentCount() == 0)" would do it then.

Comment: @NicholasEason I edited the answer to fit the additional information you provided.

Comment: So saying 'if(tiles[3][3].getComponentCount() == 0)' would work... Cool, thanks!